# Looping Batch File Extraction

Tags: batch-file

I am not very keen with batch file nor with cmd command lines but I'm at the edge where I need to use them. For instance, I'm going to need to write something as follows (but in javascript):

```
for(var i=0, i>100,i++){
    console.log("Extract this (" + i + ").extension");
    console.log("Exit if error");
}
```

...or something like that

here's the actual thing I made. (Please pardon for being noob on this)

```
@echo off
set x=0

:loop
set /a x=x+1
powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Force '%~dp0zip (" and %x% and ").zip' '%~dp0\extracted'"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
goto loop
```

My aim is to extract these files:

```
zip (1).zip
zip (2).zip
zip (3).zip
zip (4).zip
zip (5).zip
zip (6).zip
...
```

into /extracted using a batch file.

Please help me out, I'm begging you. Haha~

Comment: `cmd` doesn't use any operators to concatenate strings. `... "Expand-Archive -Force '%~dp0zip (%x%).zip' '%~dp0\extracted'" ...` should work.

Comment: @Stephan dude, it worked like a charm. Big up, bro. Thanks for letting me know, by the way

Comment: Example: `@for %%I in ("%~dp0*.zip") do @%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "Expand-Archive -Force -LiteralPath '%%I' -DestinationPath '%~dp0extracted'"` or even better not using a batch file at all and use just PowerShell with [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html) to extract all ZIP files in a directory.

Comment: @Mofi much better. Thanks, man

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, @Stephan and @Mofi with their contribution, corrected my implementation into this:

```
@echo off
set x=1

:loop
set /a x=x+1
powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Force '%~dp0zip (%x%).zip' '%~dp0\extracted'"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
goto loop
```

and it worked like magic. If there's a better and shorter way to achieve the end goal, I'd gladly check it out and try.

Answer (score 0):

*If there's a better and shorter way to achieve the end goal, I'd gladly check it out and try.*

I'm going to keep talking about powershell.

This link

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee897671-fa3a-4e06-8cb6-0986900c032e/powershell-function-unzip-all-files-in-a-folder?forum=winserverpowershell

gives this example, which in my opinion is less gibberish than batch.

```
Get-ChildItem 'path to folder' -Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'path to extract' -Force
```

Just like batch, you paste this line into a `.ps1` file. You can use the old school powershell ISE editor or Visual Studio Code

I've done many years of batch in the past and I was glad to see the end of it.

The only thing this doesn't do it increment the `i` variable but that isn't really used in your code (unless you specifically want to force a stop after 100 files)

Comment: I got used to using the common loops, so yeah, I automatically assume that's how everything works in other *languages*. Regarding the .ps1 file, it's my first time hearing it -- I will explore it. Powershell have been recommened by my higher-ups and recommended as well on most of the channels, I guess it's the right time for me to give-up the old habits of using cmd and batch

Comment: Evrey modern language lets you iterate through a collection of things without having to manage and increment a seperate index. You can see in the powershell example you don't need to have all that plumbig incrementing things. It automatically does all that for you.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can still do batch inside powershell. It's basically an extension to batch. Instead of starting a CMD window you start a powershell window. You can keep doing batch in that window or you can also do powershell.